# Angular 2 Routing to specific component based on whether user is logged in

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-routing, mean-stack

I have a created a simple application that allows a user to log in using registered credentials.

I would like to make it slightly more intuitive for the user, so that when clicking the "User" menu, they navigate to a specific component dependent on whether they are currently logged in or not.

Logged In users -> Component that allows log out

Logged out user -> Component that allows log in

---

So far, I have the following;

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./auth/auth.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    template: `
        <header class="row">
            <nav class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                    <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/authors']">Authors</a></li>
                    <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/user/logout']">User</a></li>
                    <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/user']">User</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    `
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService){}
    isLoggedIn: boolean


    ngOnInit() {
        this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.isSignedIn();
    }
}
```

However, it only seems to work on refreshing the page as the value isLoggedIn, which is populated by my service has not updated.

Any suggestion on how to best achieve this using a MEAN stack with Angular2, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The way you have it structured, you need to update `this.isLoggedIn` when someone actually logs in.  Maybe if you move it to ngOnChange instead of ngOnInit it will work (but would fire often).

Comment: I thought this may be the case, is there a better way to structure such behaviour?

Comment: I think the proper way is to use an Observable to watch the authService to see what the status is?

Answer (score 0):

Place the check inside the constructor

```
constructor(private router : Router, 
            private authService: AuthService){
   if(!this.authService.isSignedIn()){ // not of negative case
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/signin') //path
   }

}
```

Comment: Would I need to change the template to accommodate for this change?

Comment: Doesn't appear to change anything? How does it know which route option it should navigate to?

Comment: that is what you are passing to the `navigateByUrl(...)` method

Comment: Hi Aravind, still cannot seem to get this to work. Ideally I would want two links, one being the user router, that can go to either components. How does this.router.navigateByUrl(...), know which of my [routerLink] it refers to?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing the logic. Rather than attempting to reroute when user clicks a link. It now routes after loading component

```
    ngOnInit() {
    if(this.authService.isSignedIn()){
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/user/logout');
    }}
```